# Find/query a model by hour

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query data from mongoose where a specific date is anything later than 1 hour ago. The closest I was able to do was the following code, but this doesn't find by hour, it finds by day.

```
const moment = require('moment')

const today = moment(new Date()).subtract(1, "hours")

MyModel.find({
  createdAt: {
    $gte: today.toDate()
  }
})
```

How can I query by hour in mongoose?

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to get the documents where createdAt's hour part is bigger than x and the date part doesn't matter ? Like it's 4PM UTC now so you want all the documents with higher date including the ones from January, prev year etc ?

Comment: @mickl the date matters. Lemme use an example to better clarify. Say the current time is 8:30 am, and there are 100 `MyModel` documents. 50 of them were created yesterday, 40 of them we're created today at 8:00am, and 10 were created at 9am today. I want to get the 40 items which were created 8am today, and the 10 items that were created at 9am. (Created at is the wrong term to use, but that's the idea)

Comment: @Jessica Well, if it's 8:30 than the 10 documents from 9:00 haven't been created yet :)

Comment: @Mafor, that's way I said that 'created at' isn't a good terminology. lol. But that's the idea I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comment - that made it clear. The easiest way is to evaluate the date on a client side. There's a good [`startOf`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) operator you can use:

```js
const hourAgo = moment(new Date()).subtract(1, "hours").startOf('hour');
console.log(hourAgo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

```
MyModel.find({
   createdAt: {
      $gte: hourAgo.toDate()
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Just curious as to why `startOf` is useful here?

Comment: @Jessica it rounds down to a full hour. So if it's 8:30 then it will return 8:00 so that the documents that were created at 8.00 will get returned. I've started wondering if you still need the `subtract` part. You can decide since you exactly know your requirements.

Comment: Cool. Thank Mickl!!